# Make partially off screen div which will not add horizontal scroll to the screen

Tags: html, css, overflow

```css
/* body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
} */
.divOne{
    /* overflow-y: hidden; */
    position: relative;
    background-color: aqua;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
.divTwo{
    background-color: red;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    right: -80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />

    <title>learning about canvas</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-div">
      <div class="divOne">div1</div>
      <div class="divTwo">div2</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to make it so that the horizontal scroll bar wouldn't appear below. I want to make the overflowing 2 div overflow: hidden . but overflow : hidden only works when its applied to body and that causes a lot of problems.

Comment: You need to have some specified width on the parent container, then only overflow will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add absolute positioning rules for the `container-div` class, relative positioning for the `body` tag, with the `overflow-x: hidden` rule.

Now your block `.divTwo` is hidden in the viewing area, I have a width of 300x300.

```css
body {
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container-div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.divOne{
    /* overflow-y: hidden; */
    background-color: aqua;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
.divTwo{
    background-color: red;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    right: -80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />

    <title>learning about canvas</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-div">
      <div class="divOne">div1</div>
      <div class="divTwo">div2</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```